# Output of remote cmds in putty is always truncated after 80 chars

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, putty, format

I have been fruitlessly trying to get the output in the right format. I am running putty ssh commands, and the output of the command are saved to a file and transferred over.

Ignore the fact which command it is, because when I run the same command in the server in a putty session manually, the output, or redirecting output to file puts it in the right format.

Commands:

```
output=$(drush @website.dev --uri=xyz1.com  fl)
echo "$output" > xyz1.txt
output=$(drush @website.dev --uri=xyz2.com  fl)
echo "$output" > xyz2.txt
output=$(drush @website.dev --uri=xyz3.com fl)
echo "$output" > xyz3.txt
output=$(drush @website.dev --uri=xyz4.com  fl)
echo "$output" > xyz4.txt
output=$(drush @website.dev --uri=xyz5.com  fl)
echo "$output" > xyz5.txt
```

Format I get if I run commandline:

```
 National Blog                national_blog                Enabled   7.x-3.32  N 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               d 
                                                                               s 
                                                                               r 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               v 
                                                                               i 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               w 
 OpenLayers Test Example      openlayers_test_example_fea  Disabled  7.x-2.0-    
 Feature                      ture                                   beta9       
 Owl Carousel Settings        owl_carousel_feature         Enabled   7.x-1.0     
 Password Policy Feature      password_policy_feature      Disabled              
 Promo Block                  promo_block                  Disabled  7.x-1.01    
 Promo Block i18n             promo_block_i18n             Enabled   7.x-1.02    
 RH Accolade                  rh_accolade                  Disabled  7.x-1.10    
 RH Accolade Feature          rh_accolade_feature          Disabled  7.x-1.0     
 RH Accolade Translatable     rh_accolade_translatable     Enabled   7.x-1.04    
 RH Accolades i18n View       rh_accolades_i18n_view       Enabled   7.x-0.02    
 RH Accolades View            rh_accolades_view            Disabled  7.x-1.0     
 RH Banner View               rh_banner_view               Enabled   7.x-0.21    
 Article Content Type         rh_basic_page_feature        Disabled  7.x-2.07    
 RH Blog                      rh_blog                      Enabled   7.x-2.20  O 
                                                                               v 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               r 
                                                                               r 
                                                                               i 
                                                                               d 
                                                                               d 
                                                                               e 
                                                                               n
```

Format I want to get and also what I get when I run this command manually in a putty session window:

```
 RH Job Search                         rh_job_search_feature                Enabled                  Overridden
 RH Media Feature                      rh_media_feature                     Enabled   7.x-1.13       Overridden
 Media Page                            rh_media_page_feature                Disabled
 RH Metro Image Styles                 rh_metro_image_styles                Enabled   7.x-1.00
 RH Notifications Feature              rh_notifications_feature             Disabled  7.x-1.00
 Office Location Content Type          rh_office_location_feature           Enabled
 Office Locator                        rh_office_locator_feature            Enabled   7.x-1.5
 Office Locator v2                     rh_office_locator_v2_feature         Disabled  7.x-1.0
 RH Press Release i18n Content Type    rh_press_release_i18n_content_type   Enabled   7.x-1.00
 RH Promo CT                           rh_promo_content_type                Enabled   7.x-1.21
 RH Promo Feature                      rh_promo_feature                     Enabled   7.x-1.10
 RH Promo i18n Feature                 rh_promo_i18n_feature                Disabled  7.x-1.01
 RH Promo Translatable CT              rh_promo_translatable                Disabled  7.x-1.05
 RH Promo Views                        rh_promo_views                       Enabled   7.x-1.01
 RH Promo Views i18n                   rh_promo_views_i18n                  Disabled  7.x-1.00
 RH Quicktabs Feature                  rh_quicktabs_feature                 Enabled   7.x-0.03       Overridden
```

PS: I have tried even loading a putty session so putty window size that opens is not constraining and cutting off the text:

```
putty.exe -load "server session xyz" -m "D:\Projects\Drupal\scripts\daily_feature_lists\commands.txt"
```

Also tried to change almost every putty property including autowrap off, seems like nothing takes effect for the actual remote commands i am sending, only to the terminal window it opens it applies the putty configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you attempted to explicitly set a `COLUMNS` variable before executing drush?

For example:

```
output=$(COLUMNS=120 drush @website.dev --uri=xyz1.com  fl)
echo "$output" > xyz1.txt
```

Comment: That totally works! Thank you. Before this I pretty much gave up changing any options and just put all my commands in the putty gui in the (connection->ssh) remote commands window and that worked as well